# browser shows a blank screen when an asp.net core mvc application is run

Tags: asp.net-core

I have created an asp.net core mvc web application in visual studio 2019 professional edition. After a successful build when I run the application, I am getting a blank screen in the browser. It is not showing the contents of the index page.

I checked the iis by typing inetmgr in the command window. It is opening up the iis Window. I also cross-checked in the browser window by typing http://localhost/. I am able to get the welcome page in IIS.

I don't know what's the issue here. Any valuable help is appreciated.

Please find the screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: As per the screenshot's url, Its not redirecting to the required controller. URL should have controller name and action method.

Comment: Whether you are using Visual Studio 2019 debugger to run your application on IIS express? check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvJ1E.png) and [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/what-is-debugging?view=vs-2019). Besides, try to use F12 developer Console or Network tools to check if there has any error?

Answer (score 1):

Came across this issue while searching for a solution for the same problem. I tried a lot of things but none of them helped. Until I cleared my browser cache. It’s not a definite solution because I have tot do it at regular times. But I can move on for some time.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced a similar issue, it was due to the Web.config file, when the run `httpRuntime` was set to an incorrect target framework. Maybe remove the `targetFramework` parameter and see if the auto resolver resolves it.